# HashSet iterator checking letters

Tags: java, string, iterator, hashset, letter

I have a String hashset (called "names") and I want to remove from it all the Strings that contains at least one char that isn't a capital letter.
I wrote this code and it doesn't work:

```
Iterator<String> iterator=names.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    for (int i=0; i<iterator.next().length(); i++) {
        if (iterator.next().charAt(i) < 'A' || iterator.next().charAt(i) > 'Z') {
            names.remove(iterator.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another solution if you are using Java-8 by using [`removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) and regex `[A-Z]+` like so :

```
Set<String> names = //.. some inputs
names.removeIf(str -> !str.matches("[A-Z]+")); // remove if not matches [A-Z]+
```

Note in this solution you don't need to convert your list to an iterator at all, and not need to check your characters by a loop, just you can match by regex.

Answer (score 4):

There are three issues with your code:

1. You should call `iterator.next()` once in each iteration of the while loop (since each call to `iterator.next()` returns a different element).
2. You should use the `Iterator`'s remove method to delete the current element (that's the only valid way to make a structural change in a `Collection` while iterating over it).
3. You should break out of the loop when you remove the current element, in order to avoid trying to remove the same element multiple times.

   ```
   Iterator<String> iterator = names.iterator();
   while (iterator.hasNext()) {
       String str = iterator.next();
       for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
           if (str.charAt(i) < 'A' || str.charAt(i) > 'Z') {
               iterator.remove();
               break;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: You could have a check `!Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i))` instead of `str.charAt(i) < 'A' || str.charAt(i) > 'Z'`.

Comment: @Anatolii that's true if all the characters in the input strings belong to the English alphabet. Otherwise, checking `Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i))` may return true also for upper case letters of other alphabets.

Comment: Interesting. Could you please provide a source to this observation?

Comment: @Anatolii read the Javadoc of `isUpperCase()`. You'll see that it returns true not only for the characters between 'A' and 'Z', but also for characters such as  '\u00C0' '\u00C1' '\u00C2' '\u00C3' '\u00C4' '\u00C5'  etc...